# Access [i][n] element of a multi dimensional List<list<string>> in c#

Tags: c#, list

In my c# application,  I query a sql and it returns a table

ColumnA ColumnB  Date
123     Null     9/7/2017
112     Null     null

Now the data set returned by my query executor is as below:

```
            var dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
            dataAdapter.Fill(_objData, "TableObject");
var theListIamTalkingOf= (_objData.Tables["TableObject"]).Select()
                       .Where(x => !x.IsNull(0))
                       .CopyToDataTable()
                       .AsEnumerable();
return theListIamTalkingOf;
```

Now the list is

```
List
(
    [0] => List
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 
            [2] => 9/7/2017

        )
    [1] => List
        (
            [0] => 112
            [1] => 
            [2] => 

        )
    )
```

And so on....

Here what i want is to have another list with values 2nd element of inner list 
i.e

```
List (
         [0] => 9/7/2017
         [1] => 
     )
```

Please note that i don't want to create a class here, because the data I am returning is a one time thing, and the class ,if created, will be used for only this instance so I think its not the best of idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<string> thirdColumns = listOfList.Select(list=> list[2]).ToList();
```

Update: you don't have a list of list but `IEnumerable<DataRow>`

```
List<string> thirdColumns = theListIamTalkingOf.Select(row=> row[2].ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: sorry tim, i mixed my code. Will you udpate the solution with the update i made to the code. The return type after query is an IEnumberable<datarow>